# Compaction = LeveledCompactionStrategy and Counter ColumnFamily

Tags: cassandra

I consider a counter ColumnFamily. Since it holds only counters, I expect to see a large number of updates in this table.

Following http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/when-to-use-leveled-compaction, I consider using compaction = LeveledCompactionStrategy.

Is this a good idea? If yes, I would have expected counter ColumnFamilies to have compaction=LeveledCompactionStrategy by default, which seems not to be the case.

Comment: Have you got the answer? I also having the same question.

Answer (score 0):

All tables (ColumnFamilies) are set to size tiered compaction strategy by default.  There is no distinction based on the type.  This is due to the fact that choosing LCS requires thoughtful consideration.  The url you link to is the standard for determining whether or not you should enable LCS.  In general, it is not a good idea to do so unless your storage is SSDs or if your use case is write-heavy.

As is mentioned in the article, you can test the impact of LCS using [write-survey mode](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-1-1-live-traffic-sampling).  I would urge you to make use of this feature before making the switch.